# How is marginalisation being used in the proof of margin-based generalisation error bounds on AdaBoost in Freund & Schapire (2012)?

Tags: conditional-probability, boosting

I am having difficulty in making explicit the use of a standard marginalisation identity in the proof of a lemma relating to a margin-based generalisation error bound on the AdaBoost algorithm. This is lemma 5.3 on p101 of [*Boosting: Foundations and Algorithms*](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Boosting_%20Foundations%20and%20Algorithms%20%5BSchapire%20%26%20Freund%202012-05-18%5D.pdf#page=112) by Freund and Schapire (2012).

**Context.**

Prior to the part of the proof that I am struggling with, the authors state the following marginalisation identity,

> Below, $\mathbb{P}_{P}(\cdot)$ and $\mathbb{E}_{P}(\cdot)$ denote probability and expectation over the random choice of $(x, y)$ from $P$, respectively.
>
> The proof uses *marginalization*, the principle that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then the probability of any event $a$ can be computed as the expected probability of the event when one of the variables is held fixed:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(a) = \mathbb{E}_{X}[\mathbb{P}_{Y \, \vert \, X}(a | X)]$$

This is applied in the proof in the following way:

> **Lemma 5.3**
>
> Suppose $P$ is any distribution over pairs $(x, y)$. Then, for $\theta > 0$ and $n \geq 1$,
>
> $$\mathbb{P}_{P, \tilde{f}} \left( \left \vert yf(x) - y \tilde{f}(x) \right \vert \geq \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \leq \beta_{n, \theta}.$$
>
> **Proof.**
>
> Using marginalization and lemma 5.2, we have that
>
> $$\begin{aligned}
> \mathbb{P}_{P, \tilde{f}} \left( \left \vert yf(x) - y\tilde{f}(x) \right \vert  \geq \frac{\theta}{2}\right) &= \mathbb{P}_{P, \tilde{f}} \left( \left \vert f(x) - \tilde{f}(x) \right \vert \geq \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \\
> &= \mathbb{E}_{P} \left[ \mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}} \left( \left \vert f(x) - \tilde{f}(x) \right \vert \geq \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \right] \\
> &\leq \mathbb{E}_{P}[\beta_{n, \theta}] \\
> &= \beta_{n, \theta}.
> \end{aligned}$$

Here, $(x, y)$ are input-label pairs drawn from a true, unknown joint distribution $P$, so that $(x, y) \sim P$.

$\tilde{f}$ can be viewed as a function randomly drawn from a distribution $Q(\tilde{f} ; b)$. In more detail, $\tilde{f}(x)$ is constructed as follows. The authors state that when $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed, then $\tilde{f}(x)$ is given by

$$\tilde{f}(x) = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{n} \tilde{h}_i(x), \quad \tilde{h}_1, \dots, \tilde{h}_n \sim D(\tilde{h}; a).$$

That is, $\tilde{f}(x)$ is an unweighted average of $n$ i.i.d. copies of a function $\tilde{h}$ drawn randomly from $D$, each evaluated at a fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, when $x$ is fixed, $\tilde{h}_i(x) \in \{-1, 1\}$ are random variables and so $\tilde{f}(x) \in -\{-1, 1\}$ is also a random variable. They then write:

> We assume throughout this proof that $\tilde{f}$ is selected in this random manner, denoting probability and expectations with respect to its random selection by $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}}$ and $\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{f}}[\cdot]$. The particular choice of $n$ will come later.

**Question.**

*In going from the 1st equality of the proof below to the 2nd equality, can someone assist in making the decomposition of the joint distribution more explicit? In particular, does $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}}$ within $\mathbb{E}_{P}[\cdot]$ refer to a conditional probability, or a marginal probability?*

While there is an implication that $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}}$ is a conditional probability, no conditioning explicitly appears in $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}}$. On whether it is a marginal or conditional probability, I have reasoned that the two distinct sources of stochasticity are $(x, y) \sim P$ and $\tilde{f} \sim D$, and it would seem that $(x, y)$ and $\tilde{f}$ are independent -- I can imagine drawing $(x, y)$ and $\tilde{f}$ 'out of separate bags'. But then I get confused as to whether there is dependence through $x$ in $\tilde{f}(x)$.

---

**Related question.**

I previously asked this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540452/soliciting-clarity-on-notation-in-an-elementary-marginalisation-identity) about the identity only, not applied to the proof context, and received an answer by [Ben](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/173082/ben), who suggested more context would be useful in this case.

**Alternative peer reviewed source.**

The marginalisation argument, together with the notation being used here is also in the original paper, "Schapire, R. E., Freund, Y., Bartlett, P., & Lee, W. S. (1998). Boosting the margin: A new explanation for the effectiveness of voting methods. *The Annals of Statistics* , 26(5), 1651–1686. [https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1024691352"](https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1024691352%22)

Comment: I'd love to help, but I'm afraid it's unclear to me from what is given.

Comment: @Ben. If possible, could you be more specific about what is unclear? Is it the way the question is framed, notation, or just the case that it's not your subject area? Because I'd be happy to edit the question to address this.

Comment: For starters, it's unclear what it means to remove $P$ from the subscript of $\mathbb{P}$ (i.e.., what is the difference between the measures $\mathbb{P}_{P,\tilde{f}}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{f}}$) and how is it meaningful for there to be a probability measure in the absence of the initial probability distribution $P$.  Frankly, the whole set of notation used in the book (including in the previous question) is an absolute disaster.  If it were me, I'd look for a different book covering the same subject with standard statistical notation.

Comment: @Ben. Thank you, your general comments are again, deeply helpful. And it's reassuring to know that I'm not alone in finding the notation difficult to interpret, even if I can't articulate it as fluently as you have. I will take your advice on board and seek alternative sources.

Comment: I should note that it's possible that this is all well explained earlier in the book and I am just missing the context.  In any case, the notation in this book departs substantially from standard statistical notation and this makes it very slow and difficult to interpret.

Comment: @Ben. It turns out that this notation and argument appears in the original 1998 paper in the Annals of Statistics. By way of journals, it doesn't get any more "statistical" than this, so it is likely that there is a context issue at play.

Comment: Annals is notorious for (almost unreadable) papers with over-complicated notation.